# Parse Error when deploying on shared hosting ( Laravel 4 )

Tags: php, laravel-4

I for some reason am getting an error when trying to deploy my app to a shared host.

I am getting this error :

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in public_html/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 411

```
function class_uses_recursive($class)
{
    $results = [];

    foreach (array_merge([$class => $class], class_parents($class)) as $class)
    {
        $results += trait_uses_recursive($class);
    }

    return array_unique($results);
}
```

I am aware that Laravel 4 needs PHP >= 5.4 and I am currently running 5.4 on my host, as well as my dev environment (which the app runs fine) and in the code above I am aware that '[ ]' is shorthand for the older array();

This is probably something I am just overlooking but my brain seems to be not working well this morning.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you sure you have PHP5.4 on your host? looks a 5.3 error to me...

Comment: Try <?php phpinfo(); ?> and make sure that it says PHP 5.4

Comment: Ugh. You guys are absolutely right. The shared host was defaulting back to 5.3, when they run a default of 5.4. Thanks so much! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem in my linux shared hosting. when I make the default version of php from 5.3 to 5.5 it has been solved properly.

Comment: What file did you have to change the version number in order to get things working or did you have to make the change on the server control panel? I changed my version of php from running 5.3 to 5.4 but still get this problem

Comment: its work for me , using site5 shared hosting, it was usgin php 5.3 as defualt after change htaccess and insert
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
it work perfectly

Comment: @Dexture could you show us what you did? What do we have to add to the .htaccess? thanks