# Laravel Syntax Error

Tags: php, laravel-5

i just uploaded my website to a server and i'm currently trying to configure it, have had a lot of issues especially with changing the paths, right now my main issue is this:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /hermes/bosoraweb097/b1299/dom.epchurchadentaorg/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 49
```

So i went to that file to check:

```
if ( ! function_exists('app'))
{
    /**
     * Get the available container instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $make
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return mixed|\Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    function app($make = null, $parameters = []) // Line 49 error
    {
        if (is_null($make)) return Container::getInstance();

        return Container::getInstance()->make($make, $parameters);
    }
}
```

Now personally i can't see anything wrong with it and it works just fine on my localhost, could there be another issue?

Comment: php version on server and version supported by the file mismatch

Comment: You have an old version of PHP which does not support the short array syntax (i.e. `[]` instead of `array()`). If that code is from Laravel then it does not support your version of PHP. If you wrote the code, then you need to use `array()`. If you are unable to upgrade PHP then you are most likely out of luck.

Comment: Need to change version of php. take help from this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038187/parse-error-when-deploying-on-shared-hosting-laravel-4

Comment: Lol why the downvote? I wouldn't have known this if i hadn't asked, thank you all though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your PHP version is not up to date with the Laravel 5 requirements. For Laravel 5 you need:

```
The Laravel framework has a few system requirements:

PHP >= 5.4 
Mcrypt PHP Extension 
OpenSSL PHP Extension 
Mbstring PHP
Extension Tokenizer PHP Extension
```

I think your server has 5.3